# Significato di "a sacco" in questo contesto

Tags: meaning

Nel romanzo *La goccia che scava*, di Francesco Luti, ho letto (grassetto mio):

> Per distrarsi da quello schiumar tristezza, Felice scese in cucina per pranzare. Si era portato il desinare **a sacco** che prevedeva pinzimonio, panzanella e un fresco *gazpacho*.

Non capisco cosa significa l'espressione "a sacco" in questo passaggio: potreste spiegarmelo? L'ho cercata alla voce "sacco" di alcuni dizionari, incluso il *Grande dizionario della lingua italiana*, ma le accezioni che ho trovato fanno riferimento a saccheggiare, all'edilizia oppure a vestiti e niente di tutto questo sembra avere senso in questo testo.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

È evidentemente una variante (a meno che non sia un refuso) della più diffusa locuzione **al sacco**. Per citare il Treccani, alla voce [sacco](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/sacco/):

> *colazione* o *pranzo al s.*, fatti all’aperto con i viveri portati con sé nel sacco alpino oppure in una qualsiasi borsa.

Comment: Ah, grazie, @DaG: infatti, la ricerca di "pranzo a sacco" su Google dà parecchie occorrenze.